# Check this javascript for making a meme

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Below is an HTML code that i made. Actually, the issue is that when I am calling function get() onclick there is no changes appeared in my browser. However, upon clicking multiple time on the submit button show an instant change in appearence which i want but for very less duration of time (say 0.1second).

```js
var t = "top Text here";
var b = "bottom Text";
var i = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1385326/pexels-photo-1385326.jpeg";
console.log(t, b, i);
memeCanvas();


function get() {
  t = document.getElementById("topText").value;
  b = document.getElementById("botText").value;
  i = document.getElementById("imgLink").value;
  console.log(t, b, i);
  memeCanvas();
}

function memeCanvas() {
  var c = document.querySelector("#c");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var image = new Image();

  image.onload = function() {
    console.log("Image Loaded");

    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 400, 400);

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 50);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 350, 400, 50);
    ctx.strokeText(t, 10, 10);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 400, 50);
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 350, 400, 50);
    ctx.strokeText(b, 0, 370);
  }
  image.src = i;
}
```

```css
canvas {}
```

```html
<body>

  <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="topText" value="hahaha">
    <input type="text" id="botText" value="nooo">
    <input type="text" id="imgLink" value="chicken.jpg">
    <!--*here chick.jpeg is an image stored in my computer */-->
    <input type="submit" onclick="get()">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<form>` to a `<div>` that should solve your issue.

Also make sure you have a valid image on the `imgLink` for this sample I change the values so you can see it in action

```js
var t = "top Text here";
var b = "bottom Text";
var i = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1385326/pexels-photo-1385326.jpeg";

var c = document.querySelector("#c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
memeCanvas();

function get() {
  t = document.getElementById("topText").value;
  b = document.getElementById("botText").value;
  i = document.getElementById("imgLink").value;
  memeCanvas();
}

function memeCanvas() {
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {

    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 400, 400);

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 50);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 350, 400, 50);
    ctx.strokeText(t, 10, 10);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 400, 50);
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 350, 400, 50);
    ctx.strokeText(b, 0, 370);
  }
  image.src = i;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div>
    <input type="text" id="topText" value="hahaha">
    <input type="text" id="botText" value="nooo">
    <input type="text" id="imgLink" value="https://presspack.rte.ie/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2015/04/AMC_TWD_Maggie_Portraits_4817_V1.jpg">
    <input type="submit" onclick="get()">
  </div>

  <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. But will you please tell me why it works with <div> not with <form>. :-)

Comment: The `<input type="submit"` in a `<form>` do more, test it here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit